How do you prevent 2FA for every login when using a MFA-enabled B2C custom policy?
I've successfully merged two sample policies from Microsoft to create a single policy that lets a user choose between OTP or Email for two-factor authentication.  The problem is that users have to perform 2FA on every login.
How can I adjust my policy (or a B2C tenant setting) that would remember a user's 2FA for, say, 21 days, so that they don't get hit with it after every login?
These are the sample policies:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/totp

I have toyed with the MFA settings inside of the corresponding tenant, but they seem to have no effect on custom policies.


You could try something like "isActiveMFASession" in the MFA starter pack.
Note that it is persisted in "SM-MFA".
For the day limit, you could use this sample as reference, which forces a password reset after 90 days.

The gold standard approach would be to use Conditional Access based evaluation. You get some signals for free with premium P1 licensing but to get everything you'd need to change your pricing tier. Read more for B2C Identity protection here and evaluate the pricing tier at aka.ms/aadb2cpricing.
If that is not an option, you can either invoke MFA based on IP change and absolute time window or alternatively only MFA unknown devices using device fingerprinting.

We invoked MFA based on IP change and absolute time window, but needed to rollback after complaints from customers. IPv6 is the 'culprit' - your address will be changed from time to time (to ensure privacy), so this doesn't work well. We're using Conditional Access based evaluation now.
